# Is manipulating a vector of nested maps possible using zippers?

Tags: clojure

I need to turn the following input into output by applying the following two rules:

1. remove all vectors that have "nope" as last item
2. remove each map that does not have at least one vector with "ds1" as last item

```lisp
(def input
  [{:simple1 [:from [:simple1 'ds1]]}
   {:simple2 [:from-any [[:simple2 'nope] [:simple2 'ds1]]]}
   {:walk1 [:from [:sub1 :sub2 'ds1]]}
   {:unaffected [:from [:unaffected 'nope]]}
   {:replaced-with-nil [:from [:the-original 'ds1]]}
   {:concat1 [:concat [[:simple1 'ds1] [:simple2 'ds1]]]}
   {:lookup-word [:lookup [:word 'word :word 'ds1]]}])

(def output
  [{:simple1 [:from [:simple1 'ds1]]}
   {:simple2 [:from-any [[:simple2 'ds1]]]}
   {:walk1 [:from [:sub1 :sub2 'ds1]]}
   {:replaced-with-nil [:from [:the-original 'ds1]]}
   {:concat1 [:concat [[:simple1 'ds1] [:simple2 'ds1]]]}
   {:lookup-word [:lookup [:word 'word :word 'ds1]]}])
```

I was wondering if performing this transformation is possible with zippers?

Comment: Could you add some more detail to your post as to what caused you to consider zippers as a way to solve this problem?

Comment: The short answer is yes.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody mentioned that the problem is not actually **walking a vector of maps with vector values**. All the maps in example data have a single key and the key is not relevant to the filtering in question. So each map in the vector (iteration) can be fed through a predicate that **walks a vector of vectors, arbitrarily nested**. I would suggest editing the question and updating the title.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [`clojure.walk`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.walk-api.html) instead for this kind of general tree transformation. It can take a bit of fiddling to get the replacement functions right but it works nicely with any nesting of Clojure data structures, which AFAIK can be a bit more challenging in a zipper based approach.

We're looking to *shrink* our tree, so `postwalk` is my go-to here. It takes a function `f` and a tree root and goes through the tree, replacing each leaf value with `(f leaf)`, then their parents and their parents etc. until finally replacing the root. (`prewalk` is similar but proceeds from root and down to leaves, so it's usually more natural when you're growing the tree by splitting branches.)
The strategy here is to somehow construct a function that prunes any branch which meets our removal criteria, but returns any other value unchanged.

```
(ns shrink-tree
  (:require [clojure.walk :refer [postwalk]]))

(letfn[(rule-1 [node] 
         (and (vector? node) 
              (= 'nope (last node))))
       (rule-2 [node] 
         (and 
           (map? node) 
           (not-any? #(and (vector? %) (= 'ds1 (last %))) 
                     (tree-seq vector? seq (-> node vals first)))))
       (remove-marked [node] 
                      (if (coll? node) 
                        (into (empty node) (remove (some-fn rule-1 rule-2) node)) 
                        node))]
  (= output (postwalk remove-marked input)))
;; => true
```

Here the fns `rule-1` and `rule-2` try to turn your rules into predicates and `remove-marked`:

1. If a node is a collection, returns the same collection, less any members for which `rule1` or `rule2` return truthy when called with that member. To check for either one at the same time we combine the predicates with `some-fn`.
2. Otherwise returns the same node. This is how we keep values like `'ds1` or `:from-any` around.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider looking at [specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter). It supports these sorts of transformations by allowing you to select and transform arbitrarily complex structures.